# VSCode上でhaskell-ide-engineサーバーがクラッシュする

Tags: haskell, vscode

VSCode上でhaskell-ide-engineサーバーがクラッシュします。
VSCodeのエラー内容は以下の文章です。
"The Haskell HIE (test) server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted."

環境は
Windows 10 Home 64bit

Stackのインストールには、以下の公式インストーラを利用しました。
"stack-1.7.1-windows-x86_64-installer"

Stackの保存場所は、以下の通りです。
"C:\Users******\AppData\Roaming\local\bin\"

haskell-ide-engineのインストールには、以下のバッチファイルを利用しました。
"make-build-all.bat"

haskell-ide-engineの保存場所は、以下の通りです。
"D:\WorkSpace\Haskell\haskell-ide-engine"

haskell-ide-engineのためのVSCodeのUser Settingsで、以下を追加したり消したりしたのですが、ダメでした。
"languageServerHaskell.useHieWrapper": true

解決策が見当たりません......

### 追記1

Q. stack exec hie-wrapper -- --lsp --debug　の実行するとどうなったか

A. 以下が出力されました。

WWAARRNNIINNGG::  ccaacchhee  iiss  oouutt  ooff  ddaattee::  CC:://UUsseerrss//*****************//AAppppDDaattaa//LLooccaall//PPrrooggrraammss//ssttaacckk//xx8866__6644--wwiinnddoowwss//gghhcc--88..00..11\lliibb\ppaacckkaagge.ceo.ncfonf..dd\ppaacckkaaggee..ccaacchhee

gghhcc  wwiillll  sseeee a na no lodl dv iveiwe wo fo ft htihsi sp apcakcakgaeg ed bd.b .U sUes e' g'hgch-cp-kpgk gr erceaccahceh'e 't ot of ifxi.x
.
2018-08-08 23:48:53.4263808 [ThreadId 3] - run entered for hie-wrapper(hie-wrapper.EXE) Version 0.2.2.0, Git revision 17e1116e22b68b4f924b50fad730f98154335ebd (1753 commits) x86_64 ghc-8.4.3
2018-08-08 23:48:53.4323655 [ThreadId 3] - Current directory:D:\WorkSpace\Haskell
2018-08-08 23:48:53.4553304 [ThreadId 3] - Cradle directory:D:\WorkSpace\Haskell
2018-08-08 23:48:53.4854882 [ThreadId 3] - Using plain GHC version
2018-08-08 23:48:53.515408 [ThreadId 3] - Project GHC version:8.0.1
2018-08-08 23:48:53.5174025 [ThreadId 3] - hie exe candidates :("hie-8.0.1","hie-8.0")
2018-08-08 23:48:53.5213918 [ThreadId 3] - found hie exe at:C:\Users***********\AppData\Roaming\local\bin\hie.exe
2018-08-08 23:48:53.5243839 [ThreadId 3] - args:["--lsp","--debug"]
2018-08-08 23:48:53.5263814 [ThreadId 3] - launching ....

2018-08-08 23:48:53.8190441 [ThreadId 3] - Using plain GHC version
2018-08-08 23:48:53.8469706 [ThreadId 3] - Mismatching GHC versions: Project is 8.0.1, HIE is 8.4.3
2018-08-08 23:48:53.8509602 [ThreadId 3] - Run entered for HIE(hie.exe) Version 0.2.2.0, Git revision 17e1116e22b68b4f924b50fad730f98154335ebd (1753 commits) x86_64 ghc-8.4.3
2018-08-08 23:48:53.8569552 [ThreadId 3] - Current directory:D:\WorkSpace\Haskell
2018-08-08 23:48:53.8589734 [ThreadId 3] -

haskell-lsp:Starting up server ...

### 追記2

Mismatching GHC versions: Project is 8.0.1, HIE is 8.4.3
とあったので、前のGHCが完全にアンインストールできてないのか、と考え、Stack Haskell およびHIEをアンインストール後、関係しそうな4つのディレクトリを削除しました。
C:\sr
C:\Users******\AppData\Roaming\local
C:\Users******\AppData\Roaming\hoogle
C:\Users******\AppData\Roaming\ghc

もう一度、Stack HaskellおよびHIEをインストールすると、少し結果が変わり、以下のようになりました。

PS D:\WorkSpace\Haskell> stack exec hie-wrapper -- --lsp --debug
2018-08-15 22:03:02.726775 [ThreadId 3] - run entered for hie-wrapper(hie-wrapper.EXE) Version 0.2.2.0, Git revision b44b9d09e25b4889abe04b3f13b9a9d38b093371 (1772 commits) x86_64 ghc-8.4.3
2018-08-15 22:03:02.7347537 [ThreadId 3] - Current directory:D:\WorkSpace\Haskell
2018-08-15 22:03:02.7577069 [ThreadId 3] - Cradle directory:D:\WorkSpace\Haskell
2018-08-15 22:03:02.7616812 [ThreadId 3] - Using plain GHC version
2018-08-15 22:03:02.7935962 [ThreadId 3] - Project GHC version:8.4.3
2018-08-15 22:03:02.7955907 [ThreadId 3] - hie exe candidates :("hie-8.4.3","hie-8.4")
2018-08-15 22:03:02.7985831 [ThreadId 3] - found hie exe at:C:\Users******\AppData\Roaming\local\bin\hie-8.4.3.exe
2018-08-15 22:03:02.8015748 [ThreadId 3] - args:["--lsp","--debug"]
2018-08-15 22:03:02.8045669 [ThreadId 3] - launching ....

2018-08-15 22:03:02.8225188 [ThreadId 3] - Using plain GHC version
2018-08-15 22:03:02.8534491 [ThreadId 3] - Run entered for HIE(hie-8.4.3.exe) Version 0.2.2.0, Git revision b44b9d09e25b4889abe04b3f13b9a9d38b093371 (1772 commits) x86_64 ghc-8.4.3
2018-08-15 22:03:02.8614146 [ThreadId 3] - Current directory:D:\WorkSpace\Haskell
2018-08-15 22:03:02.8634106 [ThreadId 3] -

haskell-lsp:Starting up server ...

Comment: VSCodeで開こうとしているディレクトリーで、 `stack exec hie-wrapper -- --lsp --debug` を実行するとどうなりますか？

Comment: WWAARRNNIINNGG::  ccaacchhee  iiss  oouutt  ooff  ddaattee::  CC:://UUsseerrss//*****************//AAppppDDaattaa//LLooccaall//PPrrooggrraammss//ssttaacckk//xx8866__6644--wwiinnddoowwss//gghhcc--88..00..11\\lliibb\\ppaacckkaagge.ceo.ncfonf..dd\\ppaacckkaaggee..ccaacchhee

gghhcc  wwiillll  sseeee a na no lodl dv iveiwe wo fo ft htihsi sp apcakcakgaeg ed bd.b .U sUes e' g'hgch-cp-kpgk gr erceaccahceh'e 't ot of ifxi.x
.

Comment: 2018-08-08 23:48:53.4263808 [ThreadId 3] - run entered for hie-wrapper(hie-wrapper.EXE) Version 0.2.2.0, Git revision 17e1116e22b68b4f924b50fad730f98154335ebd (1753 commits) x86_64 ghc-8.4.3
2018-08-08 23:48:53.4323655 [ThreadId 3] - Current directory:D:\WorkSpace\Haskell
2018-08-08 23:48:53.4553304 [ThreadId 3] - Cradle directory:D:\WorkSpace\Haskell
2018-08-08 23:48:53.4854882 [ThreadId 3] - Using plain GHC version
2018-08-08 23:48:53.515408 [ThreadId 3] - Project GHC version:8.0.1
2018-08-08 23:48:53.5174025 [ThreadId 3] - hie exe candidates :("hie-8.0.1","hie-8.0")

Comment: 2018-08-08 23:48:53.5213918 [ThreadId 3] - found hie exe at:C:\Users\***********\AppData\Roaming\local\bin\hie.exe
2018-08-08 23:48:53.5243839 [ThreadId 3] - args:["--lsp","--debug"]
2018-08-08 23:48:53.5263814 [ThreadId 3] - launching ....

Comment: 2018-08-08 23:48:53.8190441 [ThreadId 3] - Using plain GHC version
2018-08-08 23:48:53.8469706 [ThreadId 3] - Mismatching GHC versions: Project is 8.0.1, HIE is 8.4.3
2018-08-08 23:48:53.8509602 [ThreadId 3] - Run entered for HIE(hie.exe) Version 0.2.2.0, Git revision 17e1116e22b68b4f924b50fad730f98154335ebd (1753 commits) x86_64 ghc-8.4.3
2018-08-08 23:48:53.8569552 [ThreadId 3] - Current directory:D:\WorkSpace\Haskell
2018-08-08 23:48:53.8589734 [ThreadId 3] -

Comment: これらのあとに、以下のように出て、応答が返ってこないです......
haskell-lsp:Starting up server ...

Comment: うーん、NeovimでHIEがちゃんと動いている自分のプロジェクトでも試してみましたが、特に出力は変わりませんね... 今度はVS Codeで起動したときのログを見てみましょう。 "languageServerHaskell.trace.server" という設定項目を "verbose" にしてみてください。その状態でプロジェクトを開くと、C:\Users******\AppData\Local\Temp\hie.log というパスに、VSCodeがHIEを起動させたときのログが出るようです。 参考: https://github.com/alanz/vscode-hie-server/blob/7ebb94788f7feadc8a1efb612b4fde725d1156e0/src/extension.ts#L143-L147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一応のところ、自己解決？しました。
stackのプロジェクトの作成をしていなかったのが問題のようで、個別にプロジェクトを作成するとうまくいきました。
なぜstackプロジェクトを作成せずグローバルプロジェクトではhieがクラッシュしてしまうのか、根本の原因を調べる体力がないため解決とします。